# How to use two `IFS` in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ifs

So I know I can use a single `IFS` in a read statement, but is it possible to use two. For instance if I have the text

```
variable = 5 + 1;
print variable;
```

And I have the code to assign every word split to an array, but I also want to split at the `;` as well as a space, if it comes up.

Here is the code so far

```sh
INPUT="$1"

declare -a raw_parse
while IFS=' ' read -r -a raw_input; do
  for raw in "${raw_input[@]}"; do
    raw_parse+=("$raw")
  done
done < "$INPUT"
```

What comes out:

```sh
declare -a raw_parse=([0]="variable" [1]="=" [2]="5" [3]="+" [4]="1;" [5]="print" [6]="variable;")
```

What I want:

```sh
declare -a raw_parse=([0]="variable" [1]="=" [2]="5" [3]="+" [4]="1" [5]=";" [6]="print" [7]="variable" [8]=";")
```

Comment: Use `IFS=' ;'`?

Comment: That does take away the `;` at the end of the words, but it doesn't keep them in the array, it just removes them, which I don't want.

Comment: You wrote in your question "*I also want to split at the ; as well as a space*".

Comment: You can't split on a character and have it still be there in the data. And while you can probably build what you want with regular expressions and `BASH_REMATCH`, I'd strongly encourage you to consider using a language that has real parser generators available if you're trying to interpret source code as input.

Comment: So is the only way to space out the semicolons?

Comment: It's not the _only_ way, but you'll be reimplementing your own equivalent to `read -a` to avoid it.

Comment: @Twilight Either space them out or do some other sort of parsing. `IFS` does not do what you want.

Comment: That said... what's the actual use case here? I wonder if there might be a better way to accomplish the larger goal, whatever that may be.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm simply experimenting with bash's capabilities compared to other languages. I'm really interested in how parsers work and wanted to at least try baby steps in a language I know and use all the time, but python is probably better for this

Comment: A workaround with GNU sed: `read -r -a raw_input < <(sed -z 's/;/ ;/g; s/\n/ /g' "$INPUT"); declare -p raw_input`

Comment: That works, thank you, can you post that as the answer!

Comment: @Twilight: I've posted it now as answer.

Comment: Hand-rolling one is not a good place to start if your goal is to figure out how parsers work. This is a place where academia produced a robust set of theoretical underpinnings that are pretty much universally used by folks doing this work in practice; it's much more productive to spend your time with material informed by that theory.

Comment: The classic textbook (the one the compiler design class I took twenty-some-odd years ago) is the Dragon Book by Aho, Sethi and Ullman; but I'm certain it's not the only good option available. Really, though, learn the theory -- don't be another person building crappy hand-rolled parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround with GNU `sed`. This inserts a space before every `;` and replaces every newline with a space.

```
read -r -a raw_input < <(sed -z 's/;/ ;/g; s/\n/ /g' "$INPUT")
declare -p raw_input
```

Output:

```
declare -a raw_input=([0]="variable" [1]="=" [2]="5" [3]="+" [4]="1" [5]=";" [6]="print" [7]="variable" [8]=";")
```